# Regex - match any digit in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "depth10 shown"; 
    var depth= str.match(/^depth[\d+$]/);
    console.log(depth);
}
```

My function is trying to find if depth* is present in the string, where * is always numeric (ex: depth0, depth1, depth100) and return the numeric value in it. In the example above, depth is always returning only one digit instead of all digits. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: `[\d+$]` will match a digit or plus or `$`

Comment: Paste your regex - minus the slashes - at [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) and it will visually show you the "One of" condition of what you've posted here. Then compare that to these two others on the site: `^depth\d+$` and `^depth(\d+)$`  Leave out the `^` and `$` anchors to see how those differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're improperly utilizing a character class, you want to use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) instead:

```
var str = 'depth10 shown or depth100 and depth1'
var re  = /depth(\d+)/gi, 
matches = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches) //=> [ '10', '100', '1' ]
```

**Note:** If you will have more than 1 "depth*" substrings in your string, you'll want to use the `exec()` method in a loop pushing the match result of the captured group to the results array.

Otherwise, you can use the match method here:

```
var r = 'depth10 shown'.match(/depth(\d+)/)
if (r)
    console.log(r[1]); //=> "10"
```

Comment: How can I always return the first one, if there are multiple "depth*" substrings? may be matches[0] ?

Answer (score 1):

`$` Matches end of input. ie. `/t$/` does not match the 't' in "eater", but does match it in "eat".

`^` Matches beginning of input. ie, `/^A/` does not match the 'A' in "an A", but does match the 'A' in "An E".

Try:

```
var str = "depth10 shown".match(/depth\d+/gi);
console.log(str[0])
```